# How to specify a column as "GENERATED ALWAYS AS" in liquibase

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Hi I am trying to create a mysql table via liquibase. One of the columns in the table needs to be

GENERATED ALWAYS AS

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

I couldn't find the right syntax to use in liquibase.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

workaround I am using for now:

```
- modifySql:
    - replace:
        dbms: mysql
        replace: GENERATED_REPLACE_VARCHAR_64
        with: VARCHAR(64) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('CAS_00', id))
```